# Cloudflare tunnel with ingress not working as expected

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-argo

I set up the cloudflare tunnel with ingress rules following the [documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/gitlab#connecting-to-cloudflare) to the best of my knowledge. Here's my `config.yml`:

```
tunnel: [my-tunnel-id]
credentials-file: /Users/me/.cloudflared/[my-tunnel-id].json
ingress:
  - hostname: sub1.myurl.com
    service: http://localhost:3000
  - hostname: sub2.myurl.com
    service: http://localhost:3001
  - service: http_status:404
```

My DNS records also contain `CNAME` entries for both `sub1` and `sub2` subdomains that point to the `[my-tunnel-id].cfargotunnel.com`.

On my machine I have the tunnel and my two apps running on `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001` successfully.

When I visit `sub1.myurl.com`, it correctly loads the app from `localhost:3000`. But when I visit `sub2.myurl.com`, it **also** loads the app from `localhost:3000` instead of `localhost:3001`.

One log statement from the cloudflared tunnel states:

```
2023-05-12T08:11:46Z INF Updated to new configuration config="{\"ingress\":[{\"originRequest\":{}, \"service\":\"http://localhost:3000\"}], \"warp-routing\":{\"enabled\":false}}" version=3
```

suggesting that it's probably not loading the ingress configuration as represented in the yml file.

However, if I test the setup locally, it says that the ingress rules are correct:

```
$: cloudflared tunnel ingress rule https://sub1.myurl.com
Using rules from /Users/me/.cloudflared/config.yml
Matched rule #1
        hostname: sub1.myurl.com
        service: http://localhost:3000
$: cloudflared tunnel ingress rule https://sub2.myurl.com
Using rules from /Users/me/.cloudflared/config.yml
Matched rule #2
        hostname: sub2.myurl.com
        service: http://localhost:3001
```

What exactly am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after trying everything and (unsuccessfully) requesting support on Cloudflare community pages, I ended up solving the problem by simply deleting and creating the tunnel anew. I also upgraded my cloudflared instance in the process.

So, the steps to delete and the create the tunnel again:

```
cloudflared tunnel delete your_tunnel_name
```

then

```
cloudflared tunnel create your_tunnel_name
```

then copy the new tunnel ID from the cli output in the terminal and complete the following steps:

1. Find and open the `config.yaml` file in the `.cloudflared` folder on your root user and paste the new tunnel ID over where the old one was.
2. Go to DNS settings of your cloudflare account and update the CNAME records for your hosts that you want routed through the tunnel so that the target points to `new_tunnel_id.cfargotunnel.com`.

Then run the tunnel, and ingress starts working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue where the updated ingress rules were not picked up despite the 'ingress rule' command clearly stating that everything is correct and should work, and after a lot of debugging logs and checking online resources I found that IF you are running `cloudflared` as a service then it starts using a cloned config file found at `/etc/cloudflared/config.yml`

So any changes made in `~/.cloudflared/config.yml` do not actually get used by the service, but they do get validated when using the command line, which is misleading.

I copied the updated rules over to `/etc/cloudflared/config.yml` and restarted the `cloudflared` service, and everything worked fine afterwards.